# Show link IDs on for web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to using JS and am looking for a way to show on the web page all of the IDs for all  links on a page, displayed like tooltips next to each  link. I am hoping to make a bookmarklet that upon clicked would make these tooltips appear.

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: First of all, is this a Javascript or Jquery question? the two are not the same. and did you even try to accomplish this on your own? give us some sample code of what you have ben trying, until then i have to downvote.

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 jQuery is javascript so tagging as both is not unusual

Comment: Jquery is a Javascript library.... so my question is once again, do Robert code in Jquery or Javascript, i know they can be mixed, but it would be great to know. if you know how annoying it is to search for Javascript questions and always reach into Jquery questions. people should not mix the two tags imo.

Comment: I have not attempted yet as i am new to js. looking for direction. ii-iml0sto1, if you don’t want to help kindly move on. i tagged both thinking it might be accomplished with either js or jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You could just inject some CSS that would do what you want

```css
/*target <a> tags that have an id attribute*/
a[id]:after{ 
  content:attr(id);
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:-1em;
  padding:0.1em 0.3em;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color:white;
  font-size:0.8em;
}
```

```html
<p>
  some text and a <a href="#" id="id-1">link</a> to test the id tooltip and 
  some more text and another <a href="#" id="id-2">link</a> to test some text and a <a href="#" id="id-3">link</a> to test the id tooltip and 
  some other <a href="#" id="id-4">link</a> to testsome text and a <a href="#" id="id-5">link</a> to test the id tooltip and 
  some more text and another <a href="#" id="id-6">link</a> to test
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Gaby. will give this a try. much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I am still trying to figure out how to accomplish this using javascript or jquery. I have a codepen using Gaby's suggestion and this is visually what I want but I am looking to create a bookmarket where once clicked would run the javascript to perform this on a webpage. 

Codepen for example of look/feel: https://codepen.io/rlewis/pen/dZxooa

Any help on how to perform this using Javascript so that I can make a bookmarklet, is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @Robert you do not have to actually find the element with JS. All you have to do is us JS to inject the CSS in the page. See https://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/KyOzXv

Comment: Thanks again Gaby! I will look over your code. I thank you for your help!